# How do you update a nested has_one resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, partials

I seem to have two problems

1) While trying to update my singular nested resource

Restaurant has_one Hour

and

Hour belongs_to Restaurant

```
resources :restaurants do
  resource :hour
end
```

with an edit link on my restaurant show page called:

```
<%= link_to 'Set Hour', edit_restaurant_hour_path([@restaurant, @restaurant.hour]) %>
```

and the edit page has a partial render that looks like:

```
<%= render :partial => 'restaurants/hours', :locals => { :hour => 'hour' } %>
```

which loads a partial named _hours.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for hour do |f| %>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span1 hours_input">
  <h3>Monday</h1>
  From
  <%= f.text_field :from_monday, :class => 'span20 hour_field'  %>
  To
  <%= f.text_field :to_monday, :class => 'span20 hour_field'  %>
</div>
<div class="span1 hours_input">
  <h3>Tuesday</h3>
  From
  <%= f.text_field :from_tuesday, :class => 'span20 hour_field' %>
  To
  <%= f.text_field :to_tuesday, :class => 'span20 hour_field'  %>
</div>
<div class="span1">
  <%= f.submit 'Set Hours' %>
</div>
</div>
```

but once I press the submit button it gives me the error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/restaurants/34/hour/edit"
```

I tried setting it as:

```
<%= form_for hour, :method => put, :html => { :action => 'update' } do |f| %>
```

but with no luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I'm using rails 3.2.3

2) My second problem is rather mysterious.

Once I press on the button

```
<%= link_to 'Set Hour', edit_restaurant_hour_path([@restaurant, @restaurant.hour]) %>
```

on the restaurant show page, it'll give the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/restaurants/34//hour/edit
```

with the double slash before //hour. I suspect this will break in production but doesn't seem to affect me in development.

Again, thanks for reading and have a good one!

Edit: Here's the rake routes--

```
  restaurant_hour POST   /restaurants/:restaurant_id/hour(.:format)      hours#create

 new_restaurant_hour GET    /restaurants/:restaurant_id/hour/new(.:format)       hours#new

  edit_restaurant_hour GET    /restaurants/:restaurant_id/hour/edit(.:format)  hours#edit

  GET    /restaurants/:restaurant_id/hour(.:format)               hours#show

  PUT    /restaurants/:restaurant_id/hour(.:format)               hours#update

  DELETE /restaurants/:restaurant_id/hour(.:format)               hours#destroy

  restaurants GET    /restaurants(.:format)                       restaurants#index

  POST   /restaurants(.:format)                                   restaurants#create

  new_restaurant GET    /restaurants/new(.:format)                restaurants#new

  edit_restaurant GET    /restaurants/:id/edit(.:format)          restaurants#edit

  restaurant GET    /restaurants/:id(.:format)                    restaurants#show

  PUT    /restaurants/:id(.:format)                               restaurants#update

  DELETE /restaurants/:id(.:format)                               restaurants#destroy

  hour GET    /:restaurant/hour(.:format)                         hours#show

  POST   /:restaurant/hour(.:format)                              hours#create

  hour_add GET    /:restaurant/hour/add(.:format)                 hours#new

  hour_edit GET    /:restaurant/hour/edit(.:format)                         hours#edit
```

Comment: Can you post the result of doing rake routes in the console?

Comment: just added the rake routes, thanks for reading!

Comment: change `resource :hour` to `resource :hours`

Comment: changed resource :hour to resource :hours but I'm still getting the same error when I submit the form. This is very frustrating! but thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, but it's apparently not the RESTful way to do it.

I just had to add:

```
<%= form_for hour, :url => { :action => "update" }, :html => { :method => 'put' } do |f| %>
```

and specify the action/method for the update to work.

Another post suggested that just using:

```
<%= form_for @hour do |f| %>
```

would have worked, too, but I wasn't having any luck with that for some reason.